# How scale ExpressJs server with Redis on Docker Compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, redis

I trying to scale my app but I can't.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  url-shortener:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/node/app/src
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
    command: npm start
      
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 6379
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data'

volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Output:

```
url-shortener_1  | Running at http://c36ea0029a41:5000
url-shortener_4  | Running at http://6b2c7e9f7797:5000
url-shortener_5  | Running at http://377fe742227a:5000
url-shortener_3  | Running at http://d4b01df76fad:5000
url-shortener_2  | Running at http://d15414dcef40:5000
```

But when I access browser:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
d4b01df76fad   url-shortner_url-shortener   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds   0.0.0.0:65230->5000/tcp   url-shortner_url-shortener_3
377fe742227a   url-shortner_url-shortener   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago   Up 14 seconds   0.0.0.0:65228->5000/tcp   url-shortner_url-shortener_5
d15414dcef40   url-shortner_url-shortener   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds   0.0.0.0:65229->5000/tcp   url-shortner_url-shortener_2
6b2c7e9f7797   url-shortner_url-shortener   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago   Up 14 seconds   0.0.0.0:65227->5000/tcp   url-shortner_url-shortener_4
c36ea0029a41   url-shortner_url-shortener   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 seconds ago   Up 14 seconds   0.0.0.0:65226->5000/tcp   url-shortner_url-shortener_1
92812b8bffac   redis:latest                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   49 seconds ago   Up 15 seconds   0.0.0.0:65225->6379/tcp   url-shortner_redis_1
```

Comment: Does this application work with only a single replica; can you reduce this Compose setup to the absolute minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem?  `Running at localhost` suggests a misconfiguration in your application; you normally need to set the application to listen on 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces") or it won't be reachable from outside its own container.

Comment: Edited. More informations about `docker ps`, change my server to listen at `0.0.0.0` and show `app.address().port` and `os.hostname()`.